# How can i iterate data through yml file until last data?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, yaml, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I need to iterate data through yml file until last data in the hash data. 
For example: Below i have a yml file which has name, city & check. Here I need to add these details by clicking on add button one by one and at last Submit the details. Can any body please suggest me a way..

### yml file:

```
samplepage:
  name: ~sequential ['first', 'second', 'third']
  city: ~sequential ['Ohmaha', 'New York', 'Coloumbia']
  check: ~sequential ['yes', 'no', 'yes']
```

### method:

```
class SamplePage
  include PageObject
  include DataMagic

  text_field(:sample_name, id: "name_value")
  text_field(:sample_city, name: "city")
  text_field(:sample_verify, name: "verify_status")
  button(:add, text: "Add")
  button(:submit, text: "Submit")

  def enter_data
    # here i need to iterate three values and add one by one
    self.sample_name = name # related data
    self.sample_city = city # related data
    self.check = check # related data
    add # added it

    # at the last (after 3 values added to grid I should click submit button)
    submit
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over a few arrays at once, you can use [zip](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip):

```
def enter_data(doc)
  names, cities, checks = doc['samplepage'].values

  names.zip(cities, checks).each do |name, city, check|
    self.sample_name = name # related data
    self.sample_city = city # related data
    self.check = check # related data
    add # added it
  end

  submit
end
```